# Pass state from component to Modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component and import it in specific screen, in this screen i have a button when clicks i open modal contain component it's a "recorder" so after i record voices i want to take this voice and save them into Parent screen as a state or something!

in the recorder component, I save voices data into state! but how can i pass it to other parent screens!?
so how can I handle it?

here is shots

Parent Screen "after click add voice I show the modal"

[Parent Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKWFe.png)

Here's a modal contain a recorder component

[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKWFe.png)

CODE

Component

> " I pass data to PassDataToModal state inside componentDidMount "

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {AudioRecorder, AudioUtils} from 'react-native-audio';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

class RecorderScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    PassDataToModal: null,
  };



  componentDidMount() {
    AudioRecorder.requestAuthorization().then(isAuthorised => {
      this.setState({hasPermission: isAuthorised});

      AudioRecorder.onFinished = data => {
        console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data));
        this.setState({PassDataToModal: data});

      };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.controls}>
          {this._renderPlayButton(() => {
            this._play();
          })}
          {this._renderRecordButton(this.state.recording)}
          {this._renderStopButton('Stop', () => {
            this._stop().then(() => this.setState({currentTime: 0}));
          })}
        </View>
        <Text style={styles.progressText}>{this.state.currentTime}s</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default RecorderScreen;
```

Parent Screen

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';
import RecorderScreen from './Recorder';

class Order extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isModalVisible: false,
    };
  }

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible});
  };
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.toggleModal}
           >
            <Icon name="mic" color="#333" size={20} />
            <Text style={{paddingHorizontal: 5}}>Add Voice</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
         <Modal
           style={{margin: 0}}
           isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}
         >
           <View>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleModal}>
                <Icon name="close" color="#000" size={25} />
              </TouchableOpacity>

              <RecorderScreen /> // Component

            </View>
        </View>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please try to limit your posts to the specific/minimum amount of code required to illustrate the problem you're facing.  I can't even find a Modal component in here

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisB. can you check it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your parent component pass a function to your `RecorderScreen` component that will send the necessary data up. [Docs on lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up).

So in your parent you'd have something like:

```js
setData = (data) => {
  // Set this to whatever you need it to be named
  this.setState({childData: data});
}
```

Then pass the function as a prop:

```js
<RecorderScreen setData={this.setData} />
```

And finally, call it in the child however needed (If I'm following the code something like this):

```js
 componentDidMount() {
    AudioRecorder.requestAuthorization().then(isAuthorised => {
      this.setState({hasPermission: isAuthorised});
      AudioRecorder.onFinished = data => {
        this.props.setData(data);
      };
    });
  }
```

Then your parent component will have access to the child's data that you have lifted up.

Comment: Great that's work, Now just to understand, if i have a data and i want to pass it to parent i just add `this.props.whatever(data)` in my child component and in parent i just take it `<child whatever={this.whateverFuncInParent} />` that's right?

Comment: Yep! The docs I linked can probably explain it better than I can, so it'd probably be helpful to read through that page if you have a few minutes. It's a very important pattern in react so it'd be worth spending some time to make sure it makes sense

Comment: Hello Brian, it's should mater name `setData` function equal prop name?

Comment: The prop name does not have to match the function name, it can be anything you want as long as you access it correctly. Sometimes it's just clearer when tracing where props originate from. But thats not always the case, so naming your props depends on the specific case.